# Changing group cover image using fb graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I want to change the cover image of group created via graph API. Here is the code that I used but it give me error. I am using app access token.

```
$response = $facebook->api('/Groupid', "POST", 
    array (
        'access_token' => $app_token,
        'cover_url' => 'calnder.png'
    )
);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred. thrown in /home/groupsme/public_html/base_facebook.php on line 959

Can somebody tell me about my fault please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cover_url should be an absolute path to an image.

Please test it via Graph explorer first. Access token will be app token means

```
$app_token = $app_id | $app_secret;
$cover_url = "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff";
```

then do this

```
$response = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID', "POST", array ( 'access_token' => $app_token,'cover_url' => $cover_url ));
print_r($response);
```

For reference see the graph explorer screenshot

[image: A screen-shot from graph explorer]

Comment: WOW. Awesome man. Everything was correct just needed the absolute path. Thanks